# Cannot connect to any localhost connections

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I'am using Centos 6.5 with latest updates.

My problem is that whenever i try to connect to some local service it just hangs for example:

## wget

```
wget 127.0.0.1
--2014-03-11 12:43:42--  http://127.0.0.1/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80...
After a while timeout...
```

## ssh

```
# ssh 127.0.0.1 -p 6060 -v
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 6060.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 6060: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 6060: Connection timed out
```

and it hangs out to timeout.

Same with telnet, and same with connecting to irc server. External connections are running fine...

## netstat -tpln

```
# netstat -tpln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      589/sendmail        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6060              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      520/sshd            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      619/nginx           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      478/sshd            
tcp        0      0 ::1:6060                    :::*                        LISTEN      520/sshd            
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      478/sshd
```

## netstat -rn

```
# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 venet0
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U         0 0          0 venet0
```

## iptables

I arleady flush out iptables, without luck. Output form iptables:

```
# iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 634 packets, 49819 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 517 packets, 47027 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

## Loopback config

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/void 
    inet 127.0.0.1/32 scope host venet0
    inet 176.122.224.115/32 brd 176.122.224.115 scope global venet0:0
```

Turning of SELinux didn't improve it with anything.

## ip route show table local

```
# ip route show table local
local 176.122.224.115 dev venet0  proto kernel  scope host  src 176.122.224.115 
broadcast 176.122.224.115 dev venet0  proto kernel  scope link  src 176.122.224.115 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1
```

## traceroute

```
# traceroute 127.0.0.1
traceroute to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1)  0.029 ms  0.014 ms  0.012 ms
```

## ping 127.0.0.1

works ok

```
# ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.024 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.036 ms
```

The weirdest thing about it is that, i can connect to ssh, nginx server from **external** address (for ex. computer from which i ssh'ing) without problems.

This happens after ISP has rebooted my server. Thing that maybe useful is that, server was frequently updated without reboots.

Comment: oh, By the way , loop back configuration is set? , test with `ip a` or `ifconfig`.

Comment: Yup is set, http://pastebin.centos.org/8351/ or I badly read output.

Comment: @badray, you have change ip configuration last time using ifconfig and the changes has not been saved, what gives a tracert 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: @badray please [edit] your question instead of copying things in past bin, it's ok to have a miles long quesiton if the information is important. and yes you"re right `traceroute` not `tracert`. What `ping 127.0.0.1` gives you ?

Comment: @Kiwy Ok, done as you requested. Copied whole outputs to question. Ping works great. Just added it to question.

Comment: @badray now it's obviously an issue with your webserver could you show the ngnix configuration ? also what give you : `wget 127.0.0.1`

Comment: @Kiwy wget just i wrote in question, tries connect to host and hangs out. This isn't problem with webserver i think, becouse connecting to local tunnel also is timeouting, and connecting to local irc server is also timeouting... So WebServer is just one case. Look for ssh connection output.

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same issue that you describe. I was unable to connect to any listening ports on the host from local but could connect when remote.

The solution for me was to bring the lo interface back up which was down for some reason and not coming up on boot.

```
ifconfig lo up
```

After bringing the interface back up and confirming that I could see the `lo` interface with...

```
ifconfig -a
```

I was able to get on with my day... :)

I noticed that when running `ip a` that I didn't see 127.0.0.1 assigned to the lo: interface. This is what clued me in on the fact that I needed that interface to be running as well...

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. It guided me into the right direction, which was `lo` being "up" without having any IP address. `ifdown lo && ifup lo` fixed it for me, but I still think this was rather strange.

Answer (score 5):

According to the `ifconfig` output you've posted, you have the loopback address `127.0.0.1` set on two interfaces.

Try

```
ip addr del 127.0.0.1/32 dev venet0
```

and see if your loopback access is restored.

Comment: Now it look likes: http://pastebin.centos.org/8356/. Connections does not work either.

Comment: Please add the contents of your routing table (`netstat -rn`).

Comment: Here you are: http://pastebin.centos.org/8361/

Comment: @Kiwy i added always pastebin links with outputs, becouse i'am better developer than sysadmin, and I'm not always sure that i properly read the output. EDIT: after reasearch `netstat -rn` shouldnt print localhost route. `ip route show table local` should, and it does, so this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Flup answered right, but I found this question having other reason. I think alternative answer is needed. Server, I've started bind to **IPv6 socket** and I should use other address to connect like:

```
nc ::1 8080
```

or

```
curl http://[::1]:8080/
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this issue is caused by the proxy settings of your system environments.

Check the proxies with `env | grep proxy`, then unset them by:

```bash
unset http_proxy && unset https_proxy
```

This method works for my case.

Comment: This wouldn't affect the issue demonstrated with `ssh` though